# Range Join in PySpark / Spark SQL

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I'm new to Databricks and Spark, and I have a query that seems suitable for range join optimization. However, I'm struggling with selecting the right bin size, even after reading the Azure and Databricks documentation (https://rb.gy/svqp4). I've gone through the section, but I'm still unsure.

A bit of background information about my query: I use it to update a table weekly. Currently, the table contains 97,109,903 rows, with data ranging from January 1, 2017, to September 17, 2023.

My initial idea was to set the bin size to 7 because it's a weekly process. However, I encountered the following error: "Exception: Job 179 was canceled because Task 5304 in Stage 397 exceeded the maximum allowed ratio of input to output records (1 to 12,826, max allowed 1 to 10,000); this limit can be modified with the configuration parameter spark.databricks.queryWatchdog.outputRatioThreshold."

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide. Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try more bins and/or beef up the param

```
spark.databricks.queryWatchdog.outputRatioThreshold.
```

See https://docs.databricks.com/en/clusters/query-watchdog.html